# Sitecore item does not contains all fields, why?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have next code (just like prototype)

```cs
 private void WriteDataToItems(Item rootitem, IQueryable<LanguageData> languageData, SC.Globalization.Language sclng)
        {
            if (rootitem == null)
                return;
            rootitem = IncVersion(rootitem);
            Response.Write(string.Format("Item {0} - {1}<br/>", rootitem.DisplayName, rootitem.Paths.FullPath));
            rootitem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            try
            {
                foreach (Field fld in rootitem.Fields.Where(d => !d.Shared && !d.Name.StartsWith("__") && d.Name.Trim() != ""))
                {
                    Response.Write(string.Format("Processing  fld: - {0}<br/>", fld.ID.Guid.ToString()));
                    var data = languageData.FirstOrDefault(
                            d => (string.Compare(d.FieldName, fld.Name, true) == 0) && (string.Compare(d.ItemID, rootitem.ID.Guid.ToString(), true) == 0));
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        string newValue = null;
                        switch (sclng.Name)
                        {
                            case "en":
                                newValue = data.En;
                                break;
                            case "nn-NO":
                                newValue = data.nnNO;
                                break;
                            case "sv-SE":
                                newValue = data.svSE;
                                break;
                            case "da-DK":
                                newValue = data.DaDK;
                                break;
                            case "de-DE":
                                newValue = data.deDE;
                                break;
                            default:
                                newValue = null;
                                break;
                        }

                        if (newValue != null)
                        {
                            Response.Write(string.Format("Save field with Id:{0} New Value:{1}<br/>", fld.ID.Guid, newValue));
                            fld.Value = newValue;
                        }
                    }

                }

                rootitem.Editing.EndEdit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rootitem.Editing.CancelEdit();

            }

            foreach (Item cd in rootitem.GetChildren())
            {
                WriteDataToItems(cd, languageData, sclng);
            }

        }
```

and the issue that **rootitem.Fields** object do not contains all fields described in template, i just have a filing that it contain just fields that have some values but not contain fields with empty data

```cs
foreach (Field fld in rootitem.Fields.Where(d => !d.Shared && !d.Name.StartsWith("__") && d.Name.Trim() != ""))
```

how I can get all custom fields name ?
Should I use template data for it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `Fields.ReadAll();` before looping through all fields:

```cs
rootitem.Fields.ReadAll();
foreach (Field fld in rootitem.Fields.Where(d => !d.Shared && !d.Name.StartsWith("__") && d.Name.Trim() != ""))
```

Comment: Just out of curious: What ReadAll() does? Does this function reads the fields which are invisible too?

Comment: @RG-3: ReadAll() will get the item's template, call "GetFields" on it, and then iterate through those fields, adding each to the private _fields[] array of the FieldCollection object.

Answer (score 3):

After you are using `Fields.ReadAll()` you can release memory used by these fields with method `item.Fields.Reset();`

Here is the code for `ReadAll()` and `Reset()`:

```cs
 /// <summary>
/// Reads all.
/// 
/// </summary>
public void ReadAll()
{
  Template template = TemplateManager.GetTemplate(this._ownerItem);
  if (template == null)
    return;
  TemplateField[] fields = template.GetFields();
  this._fields = new Field[fields.Length];
  for (int index = 0; index < fields.Length; ++index)
    this._fields[index] = new Field(fields[index].ID, this._ownerItem);
}

/// <summary>
/// Resets this instance.
/// 
/// </summary>
public void Reset()
{
  this._fields = (Field[]) null;
  this._innerFields = (FieldList) null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of performance, Sitecore will not give you all fields in the `FieldCollection` in the following code, only fields with explicit values on item level, including empty string.

However, you will be able to access fields with either `Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["title"]` or with a PageEditor enabled Web Control such as sc:text: `<sc:text field="title" runat="server" />`

In order to have all the fields in the FieldCollection and iterate through them, make sure your code will include `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Fields.ReadAll()` call before your `foreach`.